# Sum the difference and calculate total

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sum

I have three models: Users, which belongs to Concerts, which belongs to Regions. A User listening to a Concert in a Region. Model belongs_to relationships set up respectively with users through => concerts.

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :concerts
  has_many :users, :through => :concerts
end
```

I have a start_time and end_time in Users model so that I can log number of minutes a User listened to a concert. In the user view I can render that by:

```
<%= user.start_time.to_i - user.end_time.to_i %>
```

But struggling with how to count total of number of minutes listened by all users at the concert level.

```
@total = @users.sum(:group=>:concert, :conditions => [???])
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, this ought work on MySQL, other DBs will have their own functions for this sort of thing. I couldn't see an obvious portable function in my search, but you could try rolling your own calculation.

```
@total = @users.sum(:select=>'TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, user.start_time, user.end_time) AS duration', :group=>:concert)
```

Comment: I'm just counting time in seconds so start_time is always 0 and end_time is an integer. I divide that by 60 elsewhere in the view to show minutes. How would the select statement above work with simpler numbers? like start_time=0 and end_time=360

Comment: If you want to sum the difference in seconds, and end_time and start_time are stored in seconds, then it's just:  `@total = @users.sum(:select => 'end_time - start_time as duration', :group => :concert)`.

Comment: Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':select=>"end_time - start_time as duration", :group=>:concert_id}) AS sum_id FROM' at line 1: SELECT SUM({:select=>"end_time - start_time as duration", :group=>:concert_id}) AS sum_id FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`concert_id` = 3

Comment: OK, I think this doesn't work how I thought it did. It looks like it might be possible with `sum`, but I'm no longer sure I actually know how it works. Perhaps `@total = @users.sum('end_time - start_time as duration', :group => :concert)`. If not, then it may need to use a different ActiveRecord method.